# How to use Asp.Net Core Identity only with User Table

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I want to use asp.net core Identity without any functionality related to roles, claims, logins etc. Only User table. Is it possible?

Comment: See [asp.net core 2 identity without roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944336/asp-net-core-2-identity-without-roles).